# jQuery uniform remove for one element

Tags: jquery, uniform

I have query related jquery. My designer user uniform and i want to remove it form one element at run time with the help jquery.
uniform : http://uniformjs.com/
like

```
<input type="checkbox" class="abc">
```

I know how to apply but don't know how to remove

apply :

```
jQuery(".interactionClassNow").uniform();
```

Remove ?

Comment: You can use .remove()

Comment: how to do this jquery(".abc").removeUniform(); is it right ?

Comment: please refresh your question what uniform means add more rendered html... do you want first occurring .abc to remove ??

Answer (score 5):

try this

```
$.uniform.restore(".interactionClassNow");
```

Comment: Hi Omar I have one anthor query in my form so many element with abc class now i am going to make clone with jquery every time new element add with abc class now i want to add uniform the last element only how can do this

Answer (score 1):

The correct syntax for doing this is  :

```
jQuery(".interactionClassNow").uniform.remove();
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use remove() method  to run time dynamically remove element

#### Check this <kbd>**[Demo jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qBURS/995/)**</kbd>

#### jQuery

```
$(".interactionClassNow").remove();
```

Comment: Hi User1153551 I have one anthor query in my form so many element with abc class now i am going to make clone with jquery every time new element add with abc class now i want to add uniform the last element only how can do this

Comment: you want tog get last class element use this  `$(".list:last")` or `$(".list:last-child")`

Comment: the qustion is how remove uniform for an element, not whole element